# Postgres: Unable to connect to domain socket

Tags: macos, postgresql, sockets, homebrew

Running `psql` gets me this:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I installed Postgres 9.3.3 using Homebrew.

`which psql` gives `/usr/local/bin/psql`

This seems to be a common issue. I'm terribly sorry to ask again, but I've gone through at least a dozen Q&As here and can't resolve the issue. A few posts I've gone through include:

- [Why am I getting a could not connect to server error for postgres in Mac OS Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321496/why-am-i-getting-a-could-not-connect-to-server-error-for-postgres-in-mac-os-lion)
- [Postgres cannot connect to server on Unix domain socket 5432](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427551/postgres-cannot-connect-to-server-on-unix-domain-socket-5432)
- [Can not connect to local PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465508/can-not-connect-to-local-postgresql)

Many thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified `postgresql.conf` to accept incoming TCP/IP connections? You should uncomment the `listen_addresses` parameter and set it to an appropriate subnet mask. Then in `pg_hba.conf` you have to add a line to enable connections to databases over TCP/IP. Both configuration files are in your data directory (don't know where that is on OSX).

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide any guidance on how to determine what an appropriate subnet mask would be?

Comment: You should look up your network configuration (as you may have noticed, I am not very familiar with OSX so can't help you with the specifics). Your ip address is likely to start with 192.168.0 and then a fourth number; this is typical for automatic network configuration behind a router with DHCP (10.0.0.* is another, less common possibility). There should also be a subnet mask in the form of 255.255.*.*; the third number often also 255, the fourth typically 0. That is your mask. If the numbers are really different,  ask your network administrator.